# Spring Integration: SMTP server

Tags: java, spring, email, smtp, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration 4.1.2.

In the program flow, at the end of a process I need to send an email. I am using the following:

```
<int:payload-type-router input-channel="response.in">
    <int:mapping type="java.lang.String" channel="response.out"/>
    <int:mapping type="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage" channel="mail.out"/>
</int:payload-type-router>

<mail:outbound-channel-adapter channel="mail.out" mail-sender="mailSender"/>
```

This is working fine.

I want to also handle the situation when the mail server is down.

I've tried the following solution but it does not work.

```
<int:chain input-channel="errorChannel" output-channel="emailErrorChannel">       
    <int:transformer ref="errorUnwrapper" />
</int:chain>
```

And the unwrapper:

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class ErrorUnwrapper {

    @Transformer
    public Message<?> transform(final ErrorMessage errorMessage) {
        Message<?> failedMessage = ((MessagingException) errorMessage.getPayload()).getFailedMessage();
        return failedMessage;
    }
}
```

But this is not working. I want to catch the exception and send a meaningful response back to the user instead of a stacktrace. And I want to do this within Spring Integration. Otherwise I'll have to write a Java mail service call with a service-activator instead of the SI `mail` extension.

Or is it a one-way component? I've just found this [blog](https://jtracdeveloper.wordpress.com/category/jtrac-with-spring-integration/) post doing the same. I've also read [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.0.M3/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler) but got nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to add the `errorChannel` to whatever starts you flow; you need to show us the rest of your configuration.

Alternatively, you can add an [ExpressionEvaluatingAdvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain) to the mail adapter; see [this sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more) for an example of using the advice.

Comment: Many thanks. You pointed me to the solution. I added the errorChannel to the http:inbound-gateway and that fixed the issue.